# Enviar correo electrónico a múltiples destinatarios laravel 8 (Mailable)

Tags: laravel-8, mail

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electrónico con un `mailable` a distintos destinatarios desde una colección y solo manda correo al primer destinatario.

Esta es la llamada desde el controlador

```
Mail::send(new NewAppEmail($toEmail));
```

Esto está en `mailable`

```
public $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
public function build()
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $d) {
           $this->to($d->email, $d->name)
            ->subject(str_replace('_', " ", config('app.name', 'Laravel')))
            ->view('mail.new_email')
            ->with(
                [
                    '$key 1' => $d->avalue1,
                    '$key 2' => $d->d->value2,
                    'name' => $d->name,
                    'email' => $d->email,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Si hago un `loop` en el controlador trabaja bien, pero tarda bastante en continuar y los correos se deben encolar

```
class NewAppEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
```

¿Alguna manera de hacer esto? ¿Alguna guía?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví así:

```
foreach ($toEmail as $key => $data) {
   Mail::to($data->staff_email)
   ->queue(
     new NewAppEmail($data)
   );
}
```